# Transferring Data from Quickbooks to FinancialForce

Tags: quickbooks, financialforce

We are using Quickbooks Enterprise (running on a local server, not hosted) and we are considering using Financial Force.  Can someone explain or point me to the procedure(s) & tool(s) that I can use to transfer our data from QBE to FF?  Thanks!

Comment: is this a one-time migration or a recurring integration?

Comment: One time migration - seems FF prefers that they assign a FF Partner & we pay for same.  Very little wiggle room - SFDC is also launching a migration tool, that is also only available to FF Partners.

Comment: you basically need to map QB CSV output to FF CSV input in the absence of any particular migration tool provided by FF. Lots of excel work + Data Loader -

Answer (score 0):

In general, you'd normally be looking for an ETL tool and there are a number of vendors that offer them for Quickbooks in the App Exchange.

The fact that your server is local could make that problematic unless you want to connect your server as an endpoint with Salesforce. Otherwise, I'd expect you to need to export the data from Quickbooks as CSV files, then import it into Salesforce using Dataloader or another tool of your choice. It's also conceivable that you could "back-up" your QuickBooks data to the cloud via the net (like uploading to a "data pool"), then have a Salesforce integration tool send it to Salesforce for you from there (not certain it would be worth the effort).

I'd recommend talking with vendors Quickbooks integration vendors on the App Exchange and/or other integration vendors to get their recommendations for how to connect your server's database with Salesforce, then decide what solution fits your budget.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  In this case, we have an internal Tech Team, so I'm looking for tools/apps/methods for us to do it ourselves.  Data Loader is an obvious first choice, but was hoping others could say tool 'X' is the best and we used same to do this task :)

Comment: Ahh, gotcha. From the phrasing of your question, I didn't at all get that was the type of question you were asking. Quicken has a published API. The question becomes, do you want to use SOAP or REST and write your own integration or do you want to use one that's already available from the App Exchange? Even at this, it's still a very broad question to try and answer.

Answer (score 0):

Getting data into FinancialForce is essentially getting data into Salesforce. Some of the objects you want to populate are FF objects, but others are standard SF objects.

So are you asking about the best Salesforce ETL tool? Is budget an issue? Flexibility? Underlying language?

I've used Talend to get data into and out of SF tons of times and its incredibly powerful. It's also a bit flaky and lacks robust documentation, but as I was using Talend's free version, that's par for the course. If people understand ERD's, and can handle a bit of scripting, they can handle Talend.

You can pay for other tools like Informatica, but the price-tag for a one-time data migration might be a bit much.

I'd say something like data loader isn't in fact your first choice. Data loader is fine for one or two objects, but chances are you'll want to run this integration again and again, building it up iteratively. You're better spent putting the hours into a migration template/script than the hours into a manual migration.

Or you could build Apex scripts in Salesforce that suck the data in (presuming you can directly access QB Enterprise, or cleanly and repeatedly export the data to an accessible structure).

Other options besides FinancialForce are Accounting Seed and Breadwinner. Sage Live might some day be a great option, but as of Dec 2015, I'd let someone else be the guinea pig.